# React-native useEffect hook refresh fetch

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to build a react-native weather app, fetching data from the openweather api using hooks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchWeather() {
    try {
      let data = await fetch(URL);
      const json = await data.json();
      dispatch({type: 'success', payload: json});
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({type: 'failure'});
    }
  }
  fetchWeather(); 
}, []);
```

This only loads the data once. I want to make sure the weather info stays up to date. What is the best way to refresh the data? Do I poll every X minutes (if so how)?

Comment: you can call the fetchWeather function when you want to refresh data

Comment: @MahdiN okay, how do I know when to refresh the data? the openweather APIs don't provide anything to help with that

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a period of time, you will call api?

try it:

```js
const [isStatus, setStatus] = useState(true)
setInterval(()=> {
   setStatus(!isStatus)
}, 3000)

useEffect(() => {
   fetchWeather();
}, [isStatus])
```

or you only can use this function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let loop = setInterval(()=> {
   fetchWeather();
  }, 3000);
 return () => clearInterval(loop);
}, [])
```

*My example applies when the application is opening*

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I tried this and it seems to work. One question: do we not need to clear interval at all? Concerned about cleanup.

Comment: It does not matter if you want to repeat this function often. 
If not, then you should manage them